# How can i get the time ( only hours)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to show the number of hours in a Grid, how ever when I use a method to get all of the columns, the results show the Date.

This is my scenario.

(My Entities)

```
public class Turno
{
    public int Cod_Turno { get; set; }
    public string Des_Turno { get; set; }
    public string Des_NombreCorto { get; set; }
    public DateTime Hor_Inicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime Hor_Fin { get; set; }
    public bool Flag_Activo { get; set; }

}
```

This is my Access Layer

```
public IList<Turno> Listar()
{
    var turnos = new List<Turno>();
    var comando = _baseDatos.GetStoredProcCommand("HOR_Listar_Turno");

    using (var lector = _baseDatos.ExecuteReader(comando))
    {
        while (lector.Read())
        {
            turnos.Add(new Turno
            {
                Cod_Turno = lector.GetInt32(lector.GetOrdinal("Cod_Turno")),
                Des_Turno = lector.GetString(lector.GetOrdinal("Des_Turno")),
                Des_NombreCorto = lector.GetString(lector.GetOrdinal("Des_NombreCorto")),
                Hor_Inicio = new DateTime(lector.IsDBNull(lector.GetOrdinal("Hor_Inicio")) ? 0  : lector.GetOrdinal("Hor_Inicio")),
                Hor_Fin = new DateTime(lector.IsDBNull(lector.GetOrdinal("Hor_Fin")) ? 0 : lector.GetOrdinal("Hor_Fin")),
                Flag_Activo = lector.GetBoolean(lector.GetOrdinal("Flag_Activo"))

            });
        }
    }

    comando.Dispose();
    return turnos;
}
```

Is there a way to get a Time in the Line to get `HOR_Inicio` and `HOR_Fin`; I only need the hours and minutes.

Comment: How are you displaying the DateTime object? As a date time will always contain a Date and a Time value.

Comment: What is the format of the `Hor_Inicio` and `Hor_Fin` columns?  Are they actualyl storing a `DATETIME`, or just a numeric hour?

Comment: The Format in DataBase about Hor_Inicio and Hor_Fin is Time column. When save the data is ok, in this format 15:00:00.0000000, however when i wanna show in data Grid is not ok, show me 12:00 a.m. but in my database is 15:00. I don't why?

Comment: @FelixMiranda What is the column type for the Hor_Inicio and Hor_Fin columns in the database?

Comment: the column type is Time in the database. Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the hours and minutes as a string you could use `DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");`